# IE not recognizing padding and border

Tags: jquery, css

On the right side of the page there are some tabs (colorways, photography and companions) which I made with jQuery. However, I noticed that IE (what a surprise) is not recognizing padding and border on the `h2` and the table under companions.

Normal browsers render it fine, just IE makes the problem.

any ideas?

```
<div class="tabbedPanels">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="firstlitab"><a href="#panel1" tabindex="1">COLORWAYS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel3" tabindex="3">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></li>
  <li class="lastlitab"><a href="#panel2" tabindex="2">COMPANIONS</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div class="panelContainer">
  <div id="panel1" class="panel">
   <p>content here</p>
  </div> <!-- end panel1 -->

  <div id="panel2" class="panel">                           
   <table class="w_table">
    <h2>Wallpaper</h2>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wallpaper1.jpg" /></a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wallpaper2.jpg" /></a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wallpaper3.jpg" /></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table class="pf_table">
    <h2 class="pfh2">Printed Fabrics</h2>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/printedfabrics1.jpg" /></a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/printedfabrics2.jpg" /></a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/printedfabrics3.jpg" /></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table class="wf_table">
    <h2 class="wfh2">Woven Fabrics</h2>
    <tr>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wovenfabrics1.jpg" /></a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wovenfabrics2.jpg" /></a></td>
     <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wovenfabrics3.jpg" /></a></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div> <!-- end panel2 -->
  <div id="panel3" class="panel">
   <p>content here</p>
  </div> <!-- end panel3 -->
 </div> <!-- end panelContainer -->
</div> <!-- end tabbedPanels -->


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.tabs a').click(function() {
     // save $(this) in a variable for efficiency
     var $this = $(this);

     // hide panels
     $('.panel').hide();
     $('.tabs a.active').removeClass('active');

     // add active state to new tab
     $this.addClass('active').blur();   
     // retrieve href from link (is id of panel to display)
     var panel = $this.attr('href');
     // show panel
     $(panel).fadeIn(250);

     // don't follow link down page
     return(false);
    }); // end click

    // open first tab
    $('.tabs li:eq(2) a').click();
}); // end ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like IE is unhappy with the `<h2>` tags between the `<table>` and `<tr>` tags.  I think if you stick them in another row with a colspan and a class to remove the 20px padding you'll have more consistent rendering.

When I modified the source in the IE developer tools, this helped:

```
<table class="w_table">
  <tr>
    <td colSpan="3" style="padding:0px;">
      <h2>Wallpaper</h2>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="firsttd"><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wallpaper1.jpg"></a></td>
    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wallpaper2.jpg"></a></td>
    <td><a href="#"><img src="images/products/companions/wallpaper3.jpg"></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yea, taking the h2 out works for h2, but the tables are still makiung problems. screw it, ill just make a separate stylesheet for ie.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code now I might say the only thing I see out of place initially is that your h2 tag is outside the td tag. That may be knocking the content beneath the padding. Also it could be benficial to post the css for the table as well

Comment: I didnt style anything with jquery, I just made the tabs work. Its styled via css stylesheet only. you can view both html and js on the page I gave the url.

Comment: SO encourages posting of relevant code on site. Foreign links typically are not looked favorably upon unless it's a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: Aah, my mistake. I see it now

Comment: I just edited my post now. It wasnt a problem for me I just thought it would be easier to view on site.

Comment: yea, taking the h2 out works for h2, but the tables are still making problems. screw it, ill just make a separate stylesheet for ie.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using? It seems to be okay on IE10

I cant see what is wrong so I'm only guessing

To remove border:

```
border:none;
```

This might help you with compatibility

```
padding: 25px; //Firefox, Most browsers
!padding: 16px; //IE7
_padding: 20px; //IE6
```

it might work for IE9

Comment: IE 9. You can actually see borders and padding on 'wallpaper' and 'printeed fabrics' ? Same as when viewed in firefox for example?